# Oracle : How to drop procedures matched by the name mask

Tags: oracle

I have created two procedures like :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure PARTNER_OWNER.test_1
 as begin

     dbms_output.put_line('Hello World 1 !'); 
 end;
```

and

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure PARTNER_OWNER.test_2
 as begin

     dbms_output.put_line('Hello World 2 !'); 
 end;
```

**Now I need to drop the procedures at the same time  (something like ):**

```
drop procedure PARTNER_OWNER.test_*;
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a select statement to generate the drop statements and then run them.

```
select 'DROP PROCEDURE PARTNER_OWNER.'||object_name||';'
from dba_objects
where object_name like 'TEST_%' and
      owner = 'PARTNER_OWNER';
```

Bobby

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use dynamic SQL. Here's an example:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure test_1
  2   as begin
  3       dbms_output.put_line('Hello World 1 !');
  4   end;
  5  /

Procedure created.

SQL> create or replace procedure test_2
  2   as begin
  3       dbms_output.put_line('Hello World 2 !');
  4   end;
  5  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec test_1;
Hello World 1 !

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec test_2;
Hello World 2 !

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Now, drop them:

```
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select object_name from user_objects
  3                  where object_type = 'PROCEDURE'
  4                    and object_name like 'TEST%')
  5    loop
  6      execute immediate 'drop procedure ' || cur_r.object_name;
  7    end loop;
  8  end;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

The result:

```
SQL> exec test_1;
BEGIN test_1; END;

      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'TEST_1' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored


SQL> exec test_2;
BEGIN test_2; END;

      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'TEST_2' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

---

Alternatively, instead of using an anonymous PL/SQL block, you can rewrite it to a procedure and reuse it later. As it accepts a parameter, you can drop any procedure. Pay attention to LIKE (so that you wouldn't drop a procedure you didn't really want to).

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_drop_prc(par_procedure_name in varchar2)
  2  is
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select object_name from user_objects
  5                  where `enter code here`object_type = 'PROCEDURE'
  6                    and object_name like upper(par_procedure_name) ||'%')
  7    loop
  8      execute immediate 'drop procedure ' || cur_r.object_name;
  9    end loop;
 10  end;
 11  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec p_drop_prc('test');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec test_1;
BEGIN test_1; END;

      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'TEST_1' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored


SQL>
```

Also, you could add another parameter - object type - so that you could drop *any* object, not just a procedure.

Obviously, quite a few options; pick the one you find the most appropriate.